# Socketio dynamic namespace connect event sometime not triggers namespace scope

Tags: node.js, kubernetes, socket.io, namespaces

I have faced a strange issue with Socket io dynamic namespace, Kubernetes. Client connected to socketio server but sometimes connection events never trigger the namespace instance.

I'm experiencing intermittent issue when using a regex expression for dynamic namespace.

**But, In case:**

- Running a single socket.io node.
- Or only one namespace
- Or without namespace

*=> it works normally !!!*

The code is working fine most of the time. It only failed when the socket.io client failed to trigger the namespace connect event.

**Note**:

- I have only one the code snippet for namespace instance in my app.
- This issue occurs when running on multiple node deployed in Kubernetes with many pods.

**Package**

> "socket.io": "^4.1.1",

> "socket.io-client": "^4.1.1",

**Server code:**

```
const tenantWorkspaces: socketio.Namespace = chatServer.io.of(/^\/\w+$/);
tenantWorkspaces.on('connection', async (socket: socketio.Socket) => {
    const tenantWorkspace = socket.nsp;
    console.log('========children namespace======');

    socket.on('clientEmit', (data) => {
      console.log('clientEmit', data);
    });

    tenantWorkspace.to(socket.id).emit('serverEmit', {data: 'server emitted !!!'});

    workspaceId = isString(socket.handshake.query.workspace_id) ? socket.handshake.query.workspace_id : null;

    console.log(`workspace: ${workspaceId}, contact: ${contactId} connected!`); // debug
};
```

**Client code**

```
     const options = {
      query: {
        'workspace_id': window.LINEBASE_WORKSPACE_ID || '',
      },
      resource: "socket.io",
      transports: ['websocket'],
      upgrade: false,
    };
    socket = io(`${socketUrl}/${namespace}`, options);

    socket.on("connect", () => {
      console.log('socket connected: ' + socket.connected); // true
      console.log('socketID:', socket.id);
    });
    
    socket.on('serverEmit', (data) => {
      console.log(`================ Connect namespace ${namespace} successfully ==============`, data);
    })
```

I spent almost two weeks to find the solution but still have no result.
Is there any solution for this issue ? My application has many namespaces so I needs using dynamic namespace instead of hard code.

Comment: Are there any solution for my issue ? :(  I'm trying hard to come up with a workaround, but there just might not be one...

Comment: Have you figured it out @thequang?

Comment: I'm trying hard to come up with a workaround, but there just might not be one. Finally, I used rooms instead of namespace. @GoonNguyen